# Query tuning - Multiple join conditions using likes

Tags: sql

I've hit a bit of a situation and my novice level SQL experience has met it's match.

I have a query

```
SELECT a.One, 
    a.Two, 
    a.Three, 
    a.Four, 
    b.One, 
    b.Two
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b on b.Four = a.Nine
        and b.Six like a.One
        and b.Seven like b.Two
```

- Table1 is 25000 rows
- Table2 is 22 million rows
- like clause works like this 'test%', so it should utilize the indexes I have and I don't think I need a full text index because its trailing and not preceding.
- I have an index that exists and works very efficiently when I use a straight equals instead of a like.

When I look at the query plan, I see that I am going through every row in table2 (which I was suprised). How does the inner join work in terms of what gets executed first? Does it combine the three columns as the join? Or does it Join with the first column, then second, then third.

Is there a better way to write this query?

Comment: Can you post 1) the `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>` output (or equivalent for your RDBMS) for each of these tables, and 2) the `EXPLAIN` output (or equivalent execution plan)?

Comment: For a performance question, you should always include the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that an index can only be used for one `like 'pattern%'` comparison.  This is an *inequality*, so index usage stops at the first one.

You might have luck by changing the query to a `union`:

```
SELECT a.One, a.Two, a.Three, a.Four, b.One, b.Two
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON b.Four = a.Nine and b.Six like a.One
UNION
SELECT a.One, a.Two, a.Three, a.Four, b.One, b.Two
FROM table1 a INNER JOIN
     table2 b
     ON b.Four = a.Nine and bb.Seven like b.Two;
```

Then, set up the indexes on `a(Nine, One)` and `b(Four, Two)`.  Although the two subqueries should use the indexes, you may get a lot of matches for the intermediate results slowing down the query.

Comment: It is worth nothing that you may want a(One, Nine) and/or b(Two, Four), depending upon which RDBMS is in play, and how it maintains and applies index statistics.